# ORA-00942 using Hibernate and @ManyToMany

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 5.1.0.

I have two pojos:

```
@Table(name = "SCHEMA1.TABLEA")
public class OBJECTA implements Serializable {
     private Collection<OBJECTB> objectsB = new ArrayList<>();

     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinTable(name = "SCHEMA1.TABLEAB", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "IDA", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "IDB", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
     @CollectionId(columns = @Column(name = "ID"), type = @Type(type = "long"), generator = "ABSEQ")
     public Collection<OBJECTB> getObjectsB() {
          return this.objectsB;
     }
}

@Table(name = "SCHEMA1.TABLEB")
public class OBJECTB implements Serializable {
     private Set<OBJECTA> objectsA;

     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "objectsB")
     public Set<OBJECTA> getObjectsA() {
         return this.objectsA;
     }
}
```

**All the tables exist: SCHEMA1.TABLEA, SCHEMA1.TABLEB and SCHEMA1.TABLEAB.**

Every SELECT work in my app, but when I try to do an INSERT or an UPDATE adding to my OBJECTA a collection of OBJECTB it crashes with the next error:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

However I can INSERT or UPDATE an OBJECTA or an OBJECTB without collections of the other class.

I guess I have an error in my mapping, but I cannot see the mistake.

The logger is not showing me the SQL:

```
Hibernate: insert into SCHEMA1.TABLEA (DESC, NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
2016-11-21 13:01:51,471 DEBUG [org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister:1253] - <Inserting collection: [domain.myapp.OBJECTA.objectsA#42]>
2016-11-21 13:01:51,471 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL:92] - <select ABSEQ.nextval from dual>
Hibernate: select ABSEQ.nextval from dual
2016-11-21 13:01:53,891 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:124] - <could not extract ResultSet [n/a]>
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: Set <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" /> then you can see the SQL statement.

Comment: I have it on, I added the stacktrace. The important part, which are the inserctions in TABLEAB aren't shown in my logger.

Comment: The query that fails, as the error log shows, is `select ABSEQ.nextval from dual`. Does the ABSEQ sequence exist? I guess not.

Comment: And that's it! I didn't have permissions. Dammit! I'm using a synonym created with another user, and I was checking if it existed with the owner, not with my APPs user. Thanks!